# Views/Twig/token error when trying to enter a custom URL

Tags: views, theming, 8, tokens

I'm creating a view that shows a list of "articles" with a contextual filter, "organization", to be shown as a block in the organization detail page. I configured the filter so that it grabs the organization ID from the URL (URL being something like `node/123`). I want the block to show 3 articles, and a "more" link that points to a page I'll build in the future. For now, I want this URL to point to the organization page (i.e. to the same page, bear with me with this part).

Now, configuring the "more" link in the view, I selected `Custom URL` on the `Link display` setting. The modal box says this:

> The following tokens are available for this link. You may use Twig
>   syntax in this field.
>
> - {{ arguments.field_organization_target_id }} == Content: Organization (field_organization) title
> - {{ raw_arguments.field_organization_target_id }} == Content: Organization (field_organization) input

Now, I assume I can use these tokens to build my URL. I tried both of them in the `Custom URL` text field, like so:

```
/node/{{ raw_arguments.field_organization_target_id }}
```

But when trying to open the page, it shows a massive error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

AssertionError: Tokens need to be valid Twig variables. in Drupal\Component\Assertion\Handle::Drupal\Component\Assertion\{closure}() (line 373 of core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/PluginBase.php).
assert('preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$/', $token) === 1', 'Tokens need to be valid Twig variables.')
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\PluginBase->viewsTokenReplace('/node/{{ raw_arguments.field_organization_target_id }}', Array)
Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\DisplayPluginBase->renderMoreLink()
...
```

The error goes on, but I think this first part shows what's relevant: this is related to Twig and the `renderMoreLink` method.

I also tried a simple URL like `/node/2`, but I get the same error (same thing without the first slash character). How can I make this work?

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Comment: @GokulNK no, I still see this error (just upgraded to 8.1.5).